# Python, getting the last element with slice() object

Tags: python, slice

How do i create a slice() object so that it would include the last element of a list/string

```py
s = 'abcdef'
s[slice(2,4)]
```

works fine.
Say I wanted to get elements from second to the end,  the equivalent of `s[2:]`

```
s[slice(2)]      # only gives first two elements, argument is interpreted as the end of the range
s[slice(2,)]     # same as above
s[slice(2, -1)]  # gives a range from second to the end excluding the last element
s[slice(2, 0)]   # gives empty as expected,  since end of range before the start
```

I can get specifically the last element with `slice(-1, -2, -1)`, this won't work correctly for more then one element.

Comment: `s[slice(2,None)]` ?

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: Try this `s[slice(-1,None)]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands you should repost your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test it with magic method `__getitem__`. The last object can be get with `slice(-1, None, None)`:

```
s = 'abcdef'

class A:
    def __getitem__(self, v):
        print(v)

a = A()
a[-1:]

print("s[-1:] = ", s[-1:])
print("s[slice(-1, None, None)] = ", s[slice(-1, None, None)])
```

Prints:

```
slice(-1, None, None)
s[-1:] =  f
s[slice(-1, None, None)] =  f
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to include the last element you can do that in the following two ways :

```
s[slice(2,6)]
```

or replace 6 with len(s)

Or you could also do:

```
s[slice(2,None)]
```

Comment: `len(s)` is clever (i should of thought of it), but 'None' is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Python sequence, including list object allows indexing. Any element in list can be accessed using zero based index. If index is a negative number, count of index starts from end.  As we want last element in list, use -1 as index.

So you can just use:

```
s= "abcdef"
print(s[-1])
```

Result:

```
f
```

Comment: I don't know if you HAVE to use slice, if so this answer is not correct. If you don't, this is a bit faster than slice.

Comment: @ Wimanicesir  i specifically need a slice() as i'm cutting out fields from different byte blocks with generic code. I used `s[slice()]` syntax in the question just for simplicity.